# Equivalent of $objectToArray using Mongodb java driver 3

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am moving a Mongodb query from Javascript to Java. The object format is as follows:

```
{
  "record": {
    "unknownName1": {
      "count": 5,
      "domain": "domain1"
    }, {
    ...
    }, {
    "unknownNameN": {
      "count": 3,
      "domain": "domainN"
    }
  }
}
```

The Javascript query has the following portion:

```
[
  { 
    $project: {
      record: { 
        $objectToArray: "$record" 
      }
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: { "$record"
  }, {
    $group: {
      device: "$record.k"
    }, 
    count: {
      $sum: "$record.v.count"
    },
    domain: {
      $min: "$record.v.domain"
    }
  }
]
```

I have translated the above to use the Mongodb Java Driver 3 api and have the following:

```
List<Bson> query = Arrays.asList(
    project(include("record")),
    unwind("$record"),
    group(computed("device", "$record.k"),
        sum("count", "$record.v.count"),
        min("domain", "$record.v.domain"))
);
```

The issue I am having is I can't seem to find an equivalent to $objectToArray using the Mongodb Java Driver and the subsequent sum and min operations depend on dot operating the k and v values generated from using $objectToArray.

Is there an equivalent way to map an object with unknown key names into the k and v format used by $objectToArray using the Mongodb Java Driver, preferrably version 3+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will do.

```
project(computed("record", eq("$objectToArray", "$record")))
```

Comment: Doesn't that set the `record` field to true/false?  I had to deal with a similar issue and this is how I solved it. I don't like overwriting fields (so I can cross-check my results) so my aggregation stage was `addFields(new Field<>("records", new Document("$objectToArray", "$record")))`.